# Denied vacation, what are my options?

Tags: united-kingdom, vacation

I requested 2 vacation days 1 week in advance.  My employer has denied the request the day before it was set to begin. I also intend to resign and I will send them the letter today.

Can I take the vacation despite their refusal? What are the consequences if I do?  What other options do I have?

Comment: The answer will depend on your employer's policies and the law of your location.  Thus, off-topic for TWP.

Comment: Resign and see how they react. There's a good chance they ask you to use up your vacation days anyway. Then the problem solves itself. If not, come back and let us know :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Handle 'Revoked' Holiday/Vacation Time?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5917/how-to-handle-revoked-holiday-vacation-time)

Comment: To the close voters, please see the expanded explanation of the company specific close reason.  **Questions about rules specific to your company are best asked to your manager or someone in HR. Questions should be able to be answered by an HR professional in another company, and shouldn't require specific legal expertise (see what is asking for legal advice?).** Any UK HR professional should be able to answer regarding rules about conditions under which vacation can be denied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be an unexcused absence and is likely grounds for dismissal.

With respect to them refusing, they have right of refusal so long as they do it minimum 2 days in advance.

> 4. Booking time off
>
> The general notice period for taking leave is at least twice as long
>   as the amount of leave a worker wants to take (eg 2 days’ notice for 1
>   day’s leave), unless the contract says something different.
>
> An employer can refuse a leave request but they must give as much
>   notice as the amount of leave requested, eg 2 weeks’ notice if the
>   leave requested was 2 weeks.

https://www.gov.uk/holiday-entitlement-rights/booking-time-off-

Comment: It is 1 day in advance, today for tomorrows leave.

Comment: I'd take a print off of that link and go see your boss to ask them to reconsider their refusal.

Comment: @shadox Sorry, please review your contract for any mention of vacation approval before going to your boss.  Be aware of any specifics that you agreed to.

Answer (score 3):

I would not take them without approval if I was in your situation. It is a good reason for them to get you fired, especially if they know you are already leaving. Getting fired from any job is never good.

From What I can see, given there are no specefic policies in your contract:

- Give them one week notice. Make the last day of your employment the day before your vacation. This is your best option in my opinion.
- Don't give any notice and tell you manager you quit on the last day before your vacation